# Chrome fetch pending sometimes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

I'm struggling trying to figure out why Chrome hangs in some fetches, front React app querying a Elastic Search cluster behind a simple express API.

These hangs only occurs sometimes, i can't find any pattern on these slowdowns, network tab wrongly reports times.

[screen capture gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flXnj.gif)

Logging using performance tab network duration is correct.

This bug occurs using a react-virtualized table when scroll to items.length-10, and ONLY when scrolling using mousewheel, if i keep pressing 'End' key to scroll to bottom (way faster than scrolling with mousewheel) times are correct (sub 100ms) and no lag.

Opera, Firefox and IE Edge flawless, Chrome fails both Linux and Windows v(68.0.3440.106)

Comment: Have you tried an earlier version of Chrome? Or even the latest version? I know a recent version (67 or 68) caused **a lot** of strange issues with the work site.

Comment: Latest version of chrome works fine.

Comment: So it's browser issue that's been fixed

Comment: Yep: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/3e3a37a78aa5eb7ff2da5adae3fa44efccf5773c